# hasMany model relation returns empty array. lLaravel Framework 5.5.40

Tags: php, arrays, model, laravel-5.5, relation

This is my first time posting here, sorry if i input something incorrectly.
So i have Forums.php

```
 <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Forums extends Model
{
    protected $table ='forums';
    public $primaryKey='id';

    public function section()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo(Section::class,'id');

   }

}
```

and Section.php

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Section extends Model
{


    public function forums()
    {
        return $this->hasmany(Forums::class,'section_id');

   }


}
```

I fallowed tutorial in which it was shown that using

```
$section=Section::find($id)->forums;
```

i should get all the forums that had fk equal to section $id, however ir returns empty array. 
I tried to output sql in terminal using:

```
$order = App\Section::find(2)->forums()->toSql()
```

where 2 is sections table id and got:

```
select * from `forums` where `forums`.`section_id` is null and `forums`.`section_id` is not
null"
```

so no wonder it returns empty array
however if i try to get section related to forum it works perfectly.

How could i fix this?

Changing hasmady to hasMany didn't fix it

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('Forums', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('Name');
            $table->string('Description');
            $table->integer('topics');
            $table->integer('Comments');
            $table->integer('Last_Post_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('Forums');
    }
}

<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddToUsers extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('Forums', function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->integer('Section_id');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

can't seem to find  sections shema though i have it's table in database or is because that shema isn't in project folder, because im not getting errors that table or col can't be found?

Comment: Probably just a typo, but it should be `hasMany` instead of `hasmany`. Can you also please post your migration files or dump of schema info? You refer to a couple of keys but we can't know which ones exists where and such.

Comment: i updated post but i'm not sure is missing schema from project folder would be the cause.

Comment: You haven't created foreign keys in your migration, so that's why this isn't working. Read up on how to create foreign keys in your migrations here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Comment: so if fk key exists in database but not in migration it could cause problems? Because i created it manualy

Comment: I wouldn't know, and I can't really help you if I don't know the exact structure of your database.

Comment: Oky i recreated sections table migration and problem got solved, no idea what was causing problem though, but thanks for help.

Comment: Weird. Glad to put you on the good path I guess? :p